# Error with grid.arrange:input must be grobs

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following R-Script:

```
    library(ggplot2)
    library(gridExtra)
    Sys.setenv(LANG ="en")
    c1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl))) + geom_bar()
    c2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl))) + geom_bar() + coord_flip()
    grid.arrange(c1, c2, ncols=1)
```

I get the following error with grid.arrange:

> Error in arrangeGrob(..., as.table = as.table, clip = clip, main =
>   main,  :    input must be grobs!

I can't figure out what causes the problem.

Here are my used versions:

> sessionInfo()
>           R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
>           Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

```
    locale:
    [1] de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/C/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8

    attached base packages:
    [1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

    other attached packages:
    [1] gridExtra_0.9.1 ggplot2_0.9.3.1

    loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
     [1] colorspace_1.2-4 digest_0.6.4     gtable_0.1.2     labeling_0.2     MASS_7.3-31      munsell_0.4.2    plyr_1.8.1       proto_0.3-10     Rcpp_0.11.1      reshape2_1.2.2  
    [11] scales_0.2.4     stringr_0.6.2    tools_3.0.2
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I liked this particular error, this is a stealthy one. Long story short, the parameter is `ncol`, not `ncols`. In your code, `1` is treated as a plot object, so that's why it fails, not because ggplots are invalid. The error message is not very helpful, which obscures the situation.

```
# same error as with ncols=1
grid.arrange(c1, c2, blah=1)
# fine
grid.arrange(c1, c2, ncol=1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems to me it's too early for me. I've double checked everything except this .... Thank you!