# Input must be grobs Error when using do.call()

Tags: r, plot, error-handling

I am trying to create four parallel coordinate plots into a big figure. Below is just toy data to make it reproducible so it has no particular meaning other than mimicking my real data of meaning.

```
library(GGally)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)
cNum=4
  x = data.frame(a=2*runif(100)-1,b=2*runif(100)-1,c=2*runif(100)-1,d=2*runif(100)-1,e=2*runif(100)-1)
  plot_i = vector("list", length=cNum)
  for (i in 1:4){
    x = x + i
    plot_i[[i]] = ggparcoord(x, columns=1:5, alphaLines=0.5)
    do.call("grid.arrange", c(plot_i, ncol=1)) 
  }
```

Here, it seems that the error occurs on the first iteration of the do.call part. I get an error:

```
Error in arrangeGrob(..., as.table = as.table, clip = clip, main = main,  : 
  input must be grobs!
```

I see this is a well-searched Error, although the solution seems to be dependent on the context. For instance, here, the user misused ncol ([Error with grid.arrange:input must be grobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23261130/error-with-grid-arrangeinput-must-be-grobs)) but that does not seem to be my situation.

Comment: `cNum` doesn't appear to be defined. Also, please be clear about what packages you have loaded. Are you sure mean mean to call `do.call` inside the loop? Not all the elements `plot_i` will be initialized on the first iteration. I'm pretty sure you have a NULL element in there that's causing the specific error

Comment: Sorry about that! I just edited it to define cNum. The library I used was GGally. I just figured out my error! I should do.call() outside of the loop!

Comment: Thanks @Pascal! It is in the GGally package. I edited that in as well. The problem is that I should have done do.call() outside of the for-loop!

Comment: @MrFlick: Can you explain what you thought about the NULL element causing errors in these situations and how it could be fixed?

Comment: You can't have a NULL element in the list you pass to grid.arrange. For example: `grid.arrange(NULL)` returns the same error.